# How to analyze effect effort has on catch of rare species?

Tags: anova, nonparametric

I have df which has year, basin, number of sampling sites per basin for each year and then percentage of rare species (this classification is arbitrary, but it groups certain species as rare based on likelihood of observing them). What I would like to do is see if amount of effort has had effect on percentage of rare species observed each year. The trend is that the more effort we put out the higher percentage of rare species we observe, but the question is there statistical significance? The data can be broken out even further by sampling areas. Is there a statistical analysis I can run to see

1. Is there a significant effect when looking at effort and rare species observed over time?
2. Does sampling location combined with effort have a significant effect on rare species observed? I assume I will need a non-parametric test, but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the counts of rare species/non rare species rather than relative proportions?  This could easily be done as a logistic regression.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_discovery_curve?

Comment: Can you please include the data (excerpt?) not as an image, but as text?